Carrying forward SQL
I have a query gets opening and closing balances for each month of customers from their transactions and then get a company total for the month. but if a customer does not have any transactions for multiple months i need to get the last closing and use it to fill all empty months.. right now im using LAG to get the last closing balance before any empty but when i carry that forward i can only carry it forward into 1 empty month which results in incorect calculation of the  company's total... any help will be appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please Edit your Question and provide details of the query you are using and an example of the result you are seeking.

found that this is line made my query working for anybody that care.
customer_month_balances AS (
    -- Combine customer-month combinations with their balances
    SELECT
        pm."customer_id",
        pm."month",
        COALESCE(mb."month_opening_balance", NULL) AS "month_opening_balance",
        COALESCE(mb."month_closing_balance", NULL) AS "month_closing_balance"
    FROM
        customer_months pm
    LEFT JOIN
        monthly_balances mb
        ON pm."customer_id" = mb."customer_id"
        AND pm."month" = mb."month"
),
propagated_balances AS (
    
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        month,
        month_opening_balance,
        month_closing_balance,
        LAST_VALUE(month_closing_balance IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id
            ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS propagated_closing_balance
    FROM
        customer_month_balances
)


I have created sample data and output based on my understanding of the question, but can edit as required.
INSERT INTO transactions (customer_id, transaction_date, balance) VALUES
(1, '2024-01-01', 1000),
(1, '2024-03-01', 500),
(1, '2024-05-01', 1000),
(2, '2024-02-01', 500),
(2, '2024-04-01', 500);

This shows transactions are missing for customer id 1 for months like February,April etc.
I then created a CTE (month_series) which would create all months based on current date for all customers, you can just use a date dimension (if you have one) and generate all the months.
The important logic lies in CTE balances_with_gaps, which will populate the closing balance for the latest previous month where it was available, that is the reason for using lt.month <= ms.month and ORDER BY and LIMIT
WITH month_series AS (
    -- Generate all months for each customer up to the max month
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id,
                    DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS month
    FROM transactions
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, 
                    DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL seq MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AS month
    FROM transactions
    JOIN (SELECT 0 AS seq UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
          UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 
          UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) AS seq
    WHERE CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL seq MONTH >= '2024-01-01'  -- Adjust the range as needed
)
,
latest_transactions AS (
    -- Get the most recent transaction per customer per month
    SELECT t.customer_id,
           DATE_FORMAT(t.transaction_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS month,
           t.balance
    FROM transactions t
)


,balances_with_gaps AS (
    -- For each customer and month, get the most recent transaction balance before that month
    SELECT ms.customer_id,
           ms.month,
           COALESCE(
               (SELECT lt.balance
                FROM latest_transactions lt
                WHERE lt.customer_id = ms.customer_id
                  AND lt.month <= ms.month
                ORDER BY lt.month DESC
                LIMIT 1), 0) AS closing_balance  -- 0 is the initial balance for months with no transactions
    FROM month_series ms
)
SELECT customer_id, month, closing_balance
FROM balances_with_gaps
ORDER BY customer_id, month;

Fiddle
You should be mostly able to convert balances_with_gaps CTE in redshift as it supports limit, I used mysql as an example.
Output


mine was something similar but there are a few things different.. im testing this and will let you know soon.. thanks

Sure, let me know

this was not working properly in redshift . found it tho and made it work.. will post it in a different answer just in case more people are looking for this
